# Issues Sending messages with TCPClient in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, networking, network-programming

I'm realizing a .NET chat application but i still have that error:
I can send only a message per connection.
For example. With the code below, i can send only one message that can be received correctly by the other peer, but if i send another message message, on the same connection,it won't be received by the remote PC.
Here is the code:

```
Dim client_TCP As New TcpClient
Private Sub send_obj(ByVal obj As Object)
    Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
    Dim tosend As Packet

    tosend.data = obj
    bf.Serialize(client_TCP.GetStream(), tosend)
    client_TCP.GetStream.Flush()
End Sub
Private Sub connect_to_port()
    Try
        client_TCP = New TcpClient(client_data.getIP(), client_data.getPort())
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
Private Sub disconnect_from_port()
    client_TCP.Close()
End Sub
```

And here is the listener:

```
Private Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles timer.Tick
    If client_TCP_listener.Pending = True Then

        ....
    End If
End Sub
```

So, to send a message I always need to do this (example):

```
    Dim b As Byte
    b = 1
    disconnect_from_port()
    connect_to_port()
    client_TCP.GetStream().WriteByte(b)
    client_TCP.GetStream().Flush()
```

I tried to put\remove the flush from both the code. Nothing happened.
Have you got any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that it is not received? Did you try emulating remote host with your own code?

TCP is a stream protocol that means that you can send two bytes doing two separate calls to client_TCP.GetStream().WriteByte(b) and the remote party can receive those 2 bytes using one Receive call. You should not make any assumptions on the I/O API call patterns (number of writes and number of receives) but analyze the data you're sending receiving via stream connection.

So to send messages using stream protocol you have to introduce the notion of the application protocol. For instance [2bytes-size][size-bytes of message] - which means that if we want to send "hello" message we at first will send 2 bytes containing the size of the "hello" string and then the string itself.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that receiving end is also using .net BinaryFormatter for deserlizing the object.